# Read the quantity of carriage return used in Word

Tags: vbscript, ms-word

I am calculating accuracy from a word document by calculating the total number of changes made once track review is on. Incorrect use of punctuation is calculated as 1/4 mark, while for contextual or grammar errors a full 1 mark is deducted.

Right now all carriage returns are being calculated as 1 full mark. I want this either to be removed completely or can pass it along as 1/4 mark deduction. I am using the following for counting . ; and , as 1/4 mark deduction.

```
For Each myRevision In ActiveDocument.Revisions
myRevision.Range.Select
    If myRevision.Type = wdRevisionInsert Then
        lngRevisions = Len(Selection.Text)
        For i = 1 To lngRevisions
            If Mid(Selection.Text, i, 1) = "," Then
                punct = punct + 1
            Else
            End If

            If Mid(Selection.Text, i, 1) = "." Then
                punct = punct + 1
            Else
            End If

            If Mid(Selection.Text, i, 1) = ";" Then
                punct = punct + 1
            Else
            End If
            If Mid(Selection.Text, i, 1) = "" Then
                punct = punct + 1
            Else
            End If
       Next i
       Count = Count + 1
    Else
    End If
Next

tCorrections = Count + punct * 0.25 - punct


Accuracy = ((tWords - tCorrections) / tWords) * 100
Accuracy = Round(Accuracy, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an array of types names (aLabels) and a string of the types occurring in your data (sC) via a mapping (aMap) of types to counting slots for a flexible way to classify your string(s). As in this demo:

```
Option Explicit

Dim aLabels : aLabels = Split("Vowels Consants Digits Punctuations EOLs Unclassified")
ReDim aCounts(UBound(aLabels))
Dim sC : sC = "abce1,2." & vbCr
Dim aMap : aMap = Array(0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4)
Dim sD : sD = sC & "d" & sC & "bb111."
Dim p, i
For p = 1 To Len(sD)
    i = Instr(sC, Mid(sD, p, 1))
    If 0 = i Then
       i = UBound(aLabels)
    Else
       i = aMap(i - 1)
    End If
    aCounts(i) = aCounts(i) + 1
Next
For i = 0 To UBound(aLabels)
    WScript.Echo Right("   " & aCounts(i), 3), aLabels(i)
Next
```

output:

```
cscript 42505210.vbs
  4 Vowels
  6 Consants
  7 Digits
  5 Punctuations
  2 EOLs
  1 Unclassified
```

Based on such raw data (frequencies of types) you an add specials weights.

**Update wrt comment:**

As I said: Add weights after calculating the raw frequencies:

```
... as above ...
Dim nSum
' Std - all weights = 1
nSum = 0 : For Each i In aCounts : nSum = nSum + i : Next
WScript.Echo "all pigs are equal:", nSum
' No EOLs
nSum = 0 : For Each i In aCounts : nSum = nSum + i : Next : nSum = nSum - aCounts(4)
WScript.Echo "EOLs don't count:", nSum
nSum = 0 : aCounts(0) = aCounts(0) * 4 : For Each i In aCounts : nSum = nSum + i : Next
WScript.Echo "vowels count * 4:", nSum
```

additional output:

```
all pigs are equal: 25
EOLs don't count: 23
vowels count * 4: 37
```

Comment: I'm sorry that is pretty confusing to me. So how do I setup the characters I want to include in the 1/4 capacity or eliminate counting it altogether.

Comment: and I would I define a carriage return as a character?

Comment: @kaswardy - you deal with carriage returns **exactly** as I did in (the first version of) my demo: concat vbCr into the types string and put the corresponding group index (4) into the map.